# Convertir Formato KODI a un Player Regular usando PHP

Tags: php, video, formato, conversión-de-tipos

Hola En estos momento para poder visualizar las emisiones de un server con Stream, en el programa KODI mediante un PHP creo este formato de archivo M3U y me funciona de maravilla. Pero me interesa poder lleva este archivo a un player como VLC o FFMEG que formato devo usar?

```
$play="#EXTM3U\n";
#$play.="#KODIPROP:inputstreamaddon,inputstream.adaptive"."\n";
#$play.="#KODIPROP:inputstream.adaptive.manifest_type=mpd"."\n";
#$play.="#KODIPROP:inputstream.adaptive.license_type=com.widevine.alpha"."\n";   
#$play.="#KODIPROP:inputstream.adaptive.server_certificate=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"."\n";
#$play.="#KODIPROP:inputstream.adaptive.license_key=https://widevine-server-vod.video.net/licenser/getlicense|Content-Type=|{"token":"29abdfaf0d2703ef91810cc51d09e2f0","device_id":"71be677682638d51","widevineBody":"b{SSM}"}|" ."\n";
#$play.= "#EXT-X-ENDLIST\n";
$play.="#EXTINF:-1,".$title_channel."\n";
$play.=$stream;
echo $play;
```

Comment: Buscando he encontrado algo como esto #EXT-X-KEY:KEYFORMAT="com.widevine.alpha",METHOD=SAMPLE-AES,URI="

Comment: podrias compartir el php que genera este m3ul tengo kodi, tengo funcionando izxi y flou , lo hize manual pero los token se vencen es para claxrovideo